# I want to configure key board shorts cuts manually in my php site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a php based web-app, it is very vast, so I want to set some keyboard shorts-cut key such as **[ { ctrl + H }, { Shift + P }.. ]** in my website. I have refereed some examples and tips, but those did not help me, so if you have any ideas about this, please suggest them to me.

I have tried ASCII keys on `keyDown` events, but it's not working. Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <script>
            var isCtrl = false;
            document.onkeyup = function(e) {
                if (e.which == 17)
                    isCtrl = false;
            }document.onkeydown = function(e) {
                if (e.which == 17)
                    isCtrl = true;
                if (e.which == 77 && isCtrl == true) {
                    alert('this is demo');
                    return false;
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Shorts Cuts</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try with jQuery event it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Above URL is a link to a nice Javascript lib for doing Javascript short cuts, the best I could find, when I did something similar. This lib also works in all recent browsers I have tested.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button accesskey="h" onClick="alert('You clicked me!');">Press Alt+H!</button>
```

`accesskey` is a powerful attribute for webapps. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDE7K/)

Comment: **it is also useful while include shortcut without any js file and easy to implement .. thank you.. Niet the Dark Absol :)**